# itext Create pdf with text wrapped around the icon

Tags: java, itext

I am trying to create a pdf using itext java library like:
[image]

Where I create  highlighter icon(the arrow sign) like:

```
Phrase ph=new Phrase("ä", FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.ZAPFDINGBATS, 14f));
```

Now I want that all the text of the advertisement ie.

> Now own a Farm Plot nr Jigani in 5yrs installment option @INR450/sqft
>   with 5acre Club House.www.goldeneraproperty.com M-9999999999

should automatically wrap around the icon which I created above using FontFactory.ZAPFDINGBATS.
However I am stuck here.Please could anyone help me resolve it.

I tried creating a table of one column and one cell and put the icon in that cell but it did not help as the text did not wrap around the table.
Please suggest how could i create a pdf where the text would automatically wrap around the icon.Thanks in Advance!!!

Answer (score 1):

I have designed it to a similar state. Please use you own alignment, fonts, sizes, etc. inside you PDF file.

**PFB the code for above design:**

```
package com.itext_dummy;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import com.itextpdf.text.Document;
import com.itextpdf.text.DocumentException;
import com.itextpdf.text.Image;
import com.itextpdf.text.Paragraph;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfPTable;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter;

public class Hello { 
    /** Path to the resulting PDF file. */
    public static final String RESULT
        = "src/hello.pdf";
    public static void main(String[] args)
        throws DocumentException, IOException {
        new Hello().createPdf(RESULT);
    }
    public void createPdf(String filename)
    throws DocumentException, IOException {
        Document document = new Document();

        PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(filename));
        document.open();

        Image img = Image.getInstance("src/Arrow.png");
        img.scaleAbsolute(50f, 50f);
        img.setAlignment(Image.LEFT | Image.TEXTWRAP);
        document.add(img);
        Paragraph para = new Paragraph();
        para.add("Now own a Farm Plot nr Jigani in 5yrs installment option @INR450/sqft with 5acre Club House.www.goldeneraproperty.com M-99999999994444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444");        
        document.add(para);
        document.close();
    }
}
```

Please do your own alignment on image size and paragraph text sizes and alignments.

**Also PFB the icon image that I used:**

[image: Arrowhead]

I used the image since, that is the only way the wrapping could be done.

**PFB my result screenshot:**
[image: Resulting pdf]

Comment: Hi Manoj.Thanks for your effort but it doesent work.I ran your code and the image overlapped on the text.Also I am looking to use font for the arrow sign due to some third party restrictions.

Comment: Ok. Let me check on the font option. If I get any details, will let you know.

Comment: You can create a `PdfTemplate` with a character from a font, and [wrap that `PdfTemplate` inside an `Image`](http://developers.itextpdf.com/question/how-add-text-absolute-position-top-first-page). Once you have that `Image`, the solution proposed by @ManoranjanJ will work. If the image overlaps with the text, you need to adjust the size of the `PdfTemplate`, but it shouldn't. The code proposed in the answer looks OK.